# Slick slider transform issue on nav slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I have a weird problem with slick slider where if I have less items than the slides to show in my nav and I am not on the first slide, if I then resize my screen, all slides before the active slide get hidden off screen.

In the example below, if you go to full screen, click on the second slide and then resize your browser, the first item in the nav slider disappears as slick transforms it out of view.

Is there a way to stop this?

```js
$(".single-item").slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  fade: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.navigation-item',
});
$(".navigation-item").slick({
  centerMode: false,
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.single-item',
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css');
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}

.slick-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-item .slick-track {
  min-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 796px) {
  .navigation-item {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='navigation-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I have more than the slides to show, it doesn't seem to move to the first slide in the nav - eg below I have 6 slides, and if I select 4 and resize, the 4 stays where it is in the nav and doesn't move to the beginning:

```js
$(".single-item").slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  fade: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.navigation-item',
});
$(".navigation-item").slick({
  centerMode: false,
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.single-item',
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css');
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}

.slick-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-item .slick-track {
  min-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 796px) {
  .navigation-item {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>3</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>4</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>5</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>6</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='navigation-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>3</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>4</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>5</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>6</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It also didn't happen in earlier versions of slick - eg in the code below using v 1.5.9, it seems to work ok (but I cannot revert to this version as we are using some features in the new slider that aren't present in the old one)

```js
$(".single-item").slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  fade: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.navigation-item',
});
$(".navigation-item").slick({
  centerMode: false,
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.single-item',
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css');
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}

.slick-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-item .slick-track {
  min-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 796px) {
  .navigation-item {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='navigation-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think this is a bug with slick so have opened an issue: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/4069

Answer (score 1):

Newer version of slick-carousel applies `transform: translate3d(-127px, 0px, 0px);` on `.slick-track` inside `.navigation-item`, although it's not entirely clear *why* it does this.

Solution (more of a hack) is to force `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` on `.slick-track`:

```js
$(".single-item").slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  fade: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.navigation-item',
});
$(".navigation-item").slick({
  centerMode: false,
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.single-item',
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css');
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}

.slick-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: none;
}

.navigation-item .slick-track {
  min-width: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)!important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 796px) {
  .navigation-item {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='navigation-item'>
    <div>
      <h3>1</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do this as when you have more than 5 items, it still needs to transform

Answer (score 0):

`

```js
 $('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  vertical:true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});

// transform issue 
  var numSlides = $('.slider-nav li').length;
     if (numSlides == 2 || numSlides == 3) {
    // Add a CSS class to the slider-nav
     $('.slider-nav').addClass('small-slides');
      }
```

```css
.slider-nav img{
  border:1px solid black;
}
/* transform issue  */
.slider-nav.small-slides .slick-track {
    transform: translateY(0)!important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
<div  class="col-md-2">
  
<ul class="slider-nav">
  <li>     <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Product-Gallery-With-Image-Zoom-xZoom/images/gallery/preview/01_b_car.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Product-Gallery-With-Image-Zoom-xZoom/images/gallery/preview/02_o_car.jpg" /></li>

</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="slider-for">
    <div>     <img class="img-fluid" class=" single_image"  src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Product-Gallery-With-Image-Zoom-xZoom/images/gallery/preview/01_b_car.jpg" /></div>
    
  <div><img class="img-fluid" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Feature-rich-Product-Gallery-With-Image-Zoom-xZoom/images/gallery/preview/02_o_car.jpg" /></div>
    

    
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.